# How to select from a datatable where the column is part of a string in C#.net

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable that I am trying to make an update on.

my datatable is the data source of a data gridview (Forms application)

I want to update all rows that are part of a textbox

the textbox contains a comma separated values such as

```
 A1,A11,B4,B38,C44
```

I have this code but stuck on how to make it working

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = (DataTable)grd1.DataSource;
        DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("'," + TextBox1.Text + ",' LIKE '%,Code,%'");
        foreach (DataRow row in dr)
        {
            row["Price"] = 1000;
        }
```

The problem is in this code

```
 "'," + TextBox1.Text + ",' LIKE '%,Code,%'"
```

it does not retuen any rows so I think I did not write it the right way.

How to fix my select line?

Note : I added a comma before and after so I do not get "T37" when I am looking for "T3"

Comment: You mean you want to search in all the columns which are mentioned in the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question wasn't easy to understand for me, but you seem to be saying that you will type a list of values into the textbox and these values are to be looked up in the [Code] column of the datatable. **I'm not clear on** whether the Code column itself is a single value or a comma separated list of codes, so I'll answer for both. Assuming the Code column is a CSV, and you want that any row where any one of the values in Code is one of these values in the textbox, shall have its price updated to 1000:

So for a textbox of "A1,B1" and a datarows like:

```
Code  Price 
A1,C3 200
B4,C7 400
```

The 200 row shall be updated and the 490 row shall not

---

I'd use LINQ for this rather than datatable select

```
var codes = textbox.Split(',');

var rows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => codes.Any(c => (r["Code"] as string).Split(',').Contains(c)));

foreach(var r in rows)
  r["Price") = 1000;
```

If you're doing this a lot I wouldn't have the codes in the row as a CSV string; a row field is allowed to be an array of strings - storing the codes as an array in the row will save having to split them every time you want to query them

---

If I've got this wrong and the row contains just a single Code value, the logic is the same, it just doesn't need the split(though the code above would work, it's not optimal):

```
var rows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r => codes.Any(c => (r["Code"] as string) == c));
```

---

And actually if you're going to be doing this a lot, I would index the datatable:

```
//if it's a csv in the datatable
var index = dt.AsEnumerable()
  .SelectMany(r => r["Code"].ToString().Split(','), (row, code) => new { R=row, C=code})
  .ToLookup(o => o.C, o => o.R);
```

This will give something like a dictionary where a code maps to a list of rows where the code appears. For a row set like

```
Code  Price 
A1,C3 200
B4,C3 400
```

You get a "dictionary" like:

```
A1: { "A1,C3", 200 }
C3: { "A1,C3", 200 },{ "B4,C3", 400 }
B4: { "B4,C3", 400 }
```

so you could:

```
foreach(var c in codesTextbox.Split)
  foreach(var row in index["c"])
    row["Price"] = 1000;
```

If the Code column doesn't contain a csv, doing a selectmany should still be fine, but to optimize it:

```
var index = dt.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(r => (string)r["Code"]);
```